# How to merge rows of a dataframe where index is the same

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe, where indexes are the same:

```
index date1 date2 date3
A      1     NaN  NaN
A     NaN    3    NaN
B      1     NaN  NaN
A     NaN    NaN  0
```

How can I transofrm it into a more concise dataframe:

```
index date1 date2 date3
A      1     3     0
B      1    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `index` is your actual index, a `groupby.first()` will do.

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).first()
print(df1)
date1  date2  date3
index
A        1.0    3.0    0.0
B        1.0    NaN    NaN
```